# Jenkins 2 Multibranch Pipelines - How can I limit the visibility/execution of branches using the Role Strategy Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2, multibranch-pipeline

I am using multibranch pipelines in projects with two branches: develop and master. This creates two subprojects, one for each branch:

```
App_Pipeline
     |---master
     |---develop
```

I have set up the Role Strategy plugin to control the authorization (visibility) of the jobs/pipelines depending on the assigned role.

**Project Roles**:

- **manager**: Uses a regexp `App_.*`
- **developer**: Uses a regexp `App_.*`

With my current roles, both types of users see the superproject (App_Pipeline), and can execute both subprojects.

The point is that I want some users (developers) to be able to see and run the develop subproject and some others (managers) to view and run both subprojects, master and develop.

I haven't found a way of configuring this yet, any idea how it can be achieved?

**UPDATE:** This is the whole context of the problem.

I'm using multibranch pipeline to scan a whole Bitbucket Project giving me:

```
ORGANIZATION
   Repo1
     |---master
     |---develop
   Repo2
     |---master
     |---develop
   Poc-repo1
     |---master
     |---develop
   Poc-repo2
     |---master
     |---develop
```

I need to support these cases:

1. Some users can read and build ONLY projects with the Poc- prefix. The shouldn't see any other project.
2. Other users can read all projects but only build develop branches
3. Finally others can read and build all projects

Comment: Are both branches being built in a single Jenkins job or do you have a parent job with two child jobs (one for master branch and one for develop)?  Sorry, I'm just a little confused by the terminology.

Comment: Actually it's not a job but a pipeline, more info here: https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins

Comment: It shouldnt matter pipeline is just a kind of job in jenkins, and from permissions view its being set the same way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supported with two-level security structure, example:

```
rol1 ".*holaArtifactoryMultibranch.*" --> read

rol2 ".*holaArtifactoryMultibranch\/master.*" --> build
```

Now, you can associate a user/group to rol1 and rol2

**UPDATE:**

I see your point, if you have an intermediate folder:

```
rol1    "^FOLDER$"   --> read

rol2    "^FOLDER\/holaArtifactoryMultibranch.*$"--> read
```

You'll see the holaArtifactoryMultibranch folder, but not others.

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve the whole problem, see the updated question