# Build access for Multi Branch Pipeline Job in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, multibranch-pipeline

In Multi Branch pipeline Jenkins job is there anyway to allow only specified users to build jobs of few branches.  Example :- branches release/* should be build only by specified users

Comment: So, I don't know is the short answer. However since you can block the entire job using Jenkins Properties: authorizationMatrix, then you should be able to get access to the same infomation: `hudson.model.Item.Build:GROUP_NAME_HERE` programatically from within the pipeline. Just may need to have admin permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins 2 Multibranch Pipelines - How can I limit the visibility/execution of branches using the Role Strategy Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666659/jenkins-2-multibranch-pipelines-how-can-i-limit-the-visibility-execution-of-br)